# Como personalizar o erro 404 usando HttpNotFound?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Segue o código abaixo:

**Controller:**

```
if (id == null)
{
    //Response.StatusCode = 404;
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

**View:**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<h2>Página não encontrada</h2>
```

Adicionei novo código **web.config:**

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/404.cshtml" />
</customErrors>
```

Resultado final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está path: Views/404/404.cshtml

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Cê tá testando local?

Comment: Muda pra `customErrors mode="On"`

Comment: Veja a resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pra você poder testar localmente, o `mode` do `customErrors` precisa ser `On`. Isso porque o `RemoteOnly` serve apenas para que estas páginas apareçam fora do ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Eu não tenho certeza se o `redirect` pode ser diretamente uma página CSHTML, acho que não, até porque não faria sentido.

Se você vai utilizar uma página completamente estática, use uma página HTML mesmo. Se for precisar de dados do servidor, faça o redirecionamento para uma *action* dentro de um *controller*.

Acho que essa segunda forma é bem melhor, até porque segue um padrão (possivelmente seu projeto todo é assim) e deixa tudo mais dinâmico, caso seja necessário personalizar a mensagem ou afins.

Observação: remova o `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` se for usar desta maneira.

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Erro/NaoEncontrado" />
</customErrors>
```

E faça um *controller* normal pra receber esta requisição.

```
public class ErroController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NaoEncontrado()
    {
        return View("CaminhoDaView");
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado jbueno, funcinou aqui.